# Parse Greater Than Value in Inner Query

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using the Parse SDK for my data storage. In my app a user is allowed to comment on something. The app also features a notifications feature where it notifies you if someone else comments you after you comment on something, similar to facebook. eg ("John Smith also commented on Sally's Workout")

My queries are as follows:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> innerQueryCommentsAlso = ParseQuery.getQuery("Comment");
    innerQueryCommentsAlso.whereEqualTo("commentOwnerID", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get("userID"));


    ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryCommentsAlsoFinal = ParseQuery.getQuery("Comment");
    queryCommentsAlsoFinal.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("commentWorkoutID", "commentWorkoutID", innerQueryCommentsAlso);
    queryCommentsAlsoFinal.whereNotEqualTo("commentOwnerID", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get("userID"));
    queryCommentsAlsoFinal.include("commentOwner");
    queryCommentsAlsoFinal.include("commentWorkout");
    queryCommentsAlsoFinal.include("commentWorkout.workoutOwner");
    queryCommentsAlsoFinal.orderByDescending("commentDate");
```

What i need to do, (or would like to do) is to only get the comments in queryCommentsAlsoFinal that occur after the last comment found in innerQueryCommentsAlso. The comment contains a field that has the comment date in it of the timestamp value, so a greater than query would would, but I'm not sure if this is possible. I could get tricky with an algorithm after getting the results but because Parse only allows 1000 returned results from a query i want to limit the results as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two steps:

1. First get the last comment of the current user.
2. Then get all comments than occurred after the last comment of the owner.

---

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> lastCommentQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Comment");
lastCommentQuery.whereEqualTo("commentOwnerID", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get("userID"));
lastCommentQuery.orderByDescending("commentDate");
lastCommentQuery.setLimit(1);
lastCommentQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Transaction>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<Transaction> list, ParseException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Date lastCommentDate = null;
            if (list.size() == 1) {
                lastCommentDate = list.get(0).getDate("commentDate");
            }
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryCommentsAlsoFinal = ParseQuery.getQuery("Comment");
            if (lastCommentDate != null) {
                queryCommentsAlsoFinal.whereGreaterThan("commentDate", lastCommentDate);
            }
            queryCommentsAlsoFinal.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("commentWorkoutID", "commentWorkoutID", innerQueryCommentsAlso);
            queryCommentsAlsoFinal.whereNotEqualTo("commentOwnerID", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get("userID"));
            queryCommentsAlsoFinal.include("commentOwner");
            queryCommentsAlsoFinal.include("commentWorkout");
            queryCommentsAlsoFinal.include("commentWorkout.workoutOwner");
            queryCommentsAlsoFinal.orderByDescending("commentDate");

            //... execute queryCommentsAlsoFinal
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was something simple I was missing. It was a case of ive seen it for so long it was hard to think outside of thar box. One more quick question for you, I'm trying to be sparing on API calls as they can be valuable, do you know if inner queries count as an extra API call even if I never call the findInBackground function? I.E. as I did it before?

Comment: If you don't call `find()` or `findInBackground(...)` on your query object, it won't communicate with Parse servers. It will be just a query object.